# What are the options to run Nextjs with Asp.Net Core Web API as a SPA?

Tags: asp.net-core, next.js, single-page-application, server-side-rendering, asp-net-core-spa-services

My main concern is the utilize the concept of Server-Side Rendering (SSR) with the Asp.Net Core API project and NextJs. I have been trying for a while to run the NextJs with Asp.Net Core API as SPA just like we do with the available templates (React or Angular) on Visual studio. But ended up with some unfamiliar issues.

In the first place, I would like to know, is it possible to use NextJs with Asp.NetCore Web API as SPA for SSR without using external dependencies? I have found some articles mentioning about razzlejs and ReactJs.Net, Is it worth using them?

I will really appreciate your guidance.

Thank you.

Comment: You could use sub-directory routing with a reverse proxy like nginx. There's a middleware in Asp.Net Core if you want to host it in a sub-directory like /api : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer#deal-with-path-base-and-proxies-that-change-the-request-path